The differences between AICc and CV in the GTWR add-in in ArcGIS
I’m currently using the GTWR add-in in ArcGIS to run my Geographically Weighted Regression (GWR) models. I’ve noticed that when I select the Cross-Validation (CV) method for bandwidth selection, the results I obtain are exactly the same as when I use the Akaike Information Criterion (AIC) method.
Given that these two methods are conceptually different—CV focuses on minimizing prediction error while AIC balances model fit and complexity—I was expecting some differences in the outcomes. However, the results seem identical.
Has anyone else experienced this, or can anyone explain why the CV and AIC methods are yielding the same results in the GTWR add-in? Any insights would be greatly appreciated!
Thanks in advance!
